# How many different proteins are able to form prions?

Tags: proteins, prion

The [Wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prion) on prions and [other sources](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC4978610/) seem to only talk about variants of PrP protein.

I think I remember a previous version of Wikipedia saying something about another protein able to form a prion.

I know there are prion-like proteins, but for this question, I want proteins that are able to form true prions. It does not matter if the protein does not form prions in humans specifically, but does in other organisms.

Comment: Welcome to Biology.SE. The Biology.SE community has agreed that **questions that show little or no prior research effort** are off-topic on this site as are ["homework"](https://biology.stackexchange.com/help/homework) questions **unless you have shown your attempt at an answer**. Please [edit] your question and tell us where you've looked for answers, what you *do* know about the topic, and where exactly you still have questions. Under researched questions may be subject to down-voting and closure. Please take the [tour] and consult the [help] starting with [ask] for details.

Comment: @tyersome I tried searching, but it just ends up with a bunch of information of PrP, because there does not seem to be much interest in the others or how many there are.

Comment: No time to write a real answer but for the diversity see https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC5131755/ The 2nd prion thing you might have heard of may have to do with Alzheimer's https://www.ucsf.edu/news/2019/05/414326/alzheimers-disease-double-prion-disorder-study-shows I think it's still controversial.

Comment: @Fizz I think it was Doppel protein which I remember, which is called Prion protein 2. It is similar and takes a bigger role in PrP null mice. No idea why researchers didn't try knocking it out too.  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PRND